# bash awk moving average with skipping

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to calculate a moving average with a data set. But in addition, I want it to skip a few number of data each time the average 'window' moves. For example, if my data set is a column from 1 to 20 and my average window is 5, then the current calculation is the average of (1-5), (2-6), (3-7), (4-8).....
But I want to skip a few data each time the window moves, say I want to skip 2. then the new average will be (1-5), (4-8), (6-10), (8-12)......
Here is the current awk file I am using, can anyone help me edit it so that I can skip a few data each time the window moves? I want to change the skip size and window size as well. Thank you very much!

```
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN {
    N=5          # the window size
}
{
    n[NR]=$1       # store the value in an array
}
NR>=N {            # for records where NR >= N
    x=0            # reset the sum variable
    delete n[NR-N] # delete the one out the window of N
    for(i in n)    # all array elements
        x+=n[i]    # ... must be summed
    print x/N  # print the row from the beginning of window
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your ranges are not well specified, but you wanted to achieve can be done by parallel windowing as below

```
awk        '{sum[1]+=$1}    
     !(NR%5){print NR-4"-"NR, sum[1]/5; sum[1]=0}
        NR>3{sum[4]+=$1}
      NR>3 && !((NR-3)%5){print NR-4"-"NR, sum[4]/5; sum[4]=0}' <(seq 15)
```

will give, you can remove printing ranges which it there for debugging.

```
1-5 3
4-8 6
6-10 8
9-13 11
11-15 13
```

for making window size and skip count variable

```
awk -v w=5 -v s=3 'function pr(x)    {print (NR-s-1)"-"NR, sum[x]/w; sum[x]=0}
                                     {sum[1]+=$1} 
                   NR>s              {sum[s+1]+=$1} 
                   !(NR%w)           {pr(1)} 
                  NR>s && !((NR-s)%w){pr(s+1)}' file
```

first window always start at 1, second window starts at s+1.  This can be generalize for more than 2 windows as well, perhaps you can find someone to do it...

Comment: Thank you so much! I made a mistake in the range, yours is correct! However, can you let me know if I want to make the 'window' and 'skip' size as variables? How should I modify this?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to print MA every K ticks instead of printing for every tick (`K=1`). So you could add a condition `NR%K==0` before printing in your existing code.

But it would be better to keep an array of N elements and overwrite them instead of deleting. Using `NR%N` as array index. This way, when K is not 1 and want not to calculate the MA, you will avoid checking how many elements to delete etc.

```
awk -v n=5 -v k=2       '{ a[NR%n]=$0 } 
    NR>=n && (NR-n)%k==0 { s=0; for (i in a) s+=a[i]; print NR ":\t" s/n }' file
```

update condition to `(NR-n)%k==0` for always starting from first tick where MA is calculated (that is for `NR=n`).